# Convolve a function(kernel) instead of multiplication?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, convolution

numpy.convolve(data,kernel) does convolve.

What I want is to convolve a function of the kernel and sliding-data instead of multiplying them, How do I do that ?

This is the function (euclidean distance) :
numpy.linalg.norm(kernel - data_frame)

thanks

---

Something like :

np.linalg.norm( (rolling_window(array([1,1,0,0,1,0,1]),2) * [0.6,0.2]) - [0,1] , axis=1)

http://www.rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html

This is a solution, but I suspect it could be better !! may be !!

Comment: Is your kernel an n-dimensional vector and your array consists of vectors?
Then a convolve like operation might not be exactly what you need.
Could you describe this a bit more detailed?

Comment: 1D array both data and kernel.

Comment: Convolution is scaling and summing. In your case, it is much more complicated operations of scaling, subtraction, squaring and then summing. If the subtraction weren't there and if the window is just of 2 elements, we can think about using convolution there though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complex but faster solution:

express your function by convolve(), your function is:

```
sqrt(sum((x[t + i] * k[i] - v[i])**2, i=0..N-1))
```

the sum() part can be expanded to:

```
convolve(x**2, k[::-1]**2) + convolve(x, (-2*k*v)[::-1]) + sum(v**2)
```

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def rolling_norm1(arr, k, v):
    return np.linalg.norm( (rolling_window(arr, len(k)) * k) - v, axis=1)

def rolling_norm2(arr, k, v):
    k = k[::-1]
    v = v[::-1]
    arr2 = arr ** 2
    k2 = k ** 2
    k1 = -2 * k * v
    c = np.sum(v**2)
    tmp = np.convolve(arr2, k2, mode="valid")
    tmp += np.convolve(arr, k1, mode="valid")
    tmp += c
    np.sqrt(tmp, out=tmp)
    return tmp
```

The results are the same:

```
a = np.random.rand(1000)
k = np.random.rand(2)
v = np.random.rand(2)

np.allclose(rolling_norm1(a, k, v), rolling_norm2(a, k, v))
```

outputs:

```
True
```

but rolling_norm2() is 2x faster:

```
%timeit rolling_norm1(a, k, v)
10000 loops, best of 3: 76.6 µs per loop

%timeit rolling_norm2(a, k, v)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31 µs per loop
```